# Angular - http.get response does not load all the Data

Tags: angular, entity-framework, angular5, asp.net-core-2.0

I 'm working on a project with ASP Core 2 in the server side, and Angular 5 in the client side, when i send an http.get request with POSTMAN all the data is loaded.

[POSTMAN OPERATION GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YleU.png)

The problem is when i send the same request with angular 5, not all the data is loaded (Check, recRes )

[Not All the Data loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC1j2.png)

Here Is My Server Code with ASP Core 2

```
 // GET: api/Reclamations/5
    [HttpGet("byClient/{id}"), Authorize]
    public async Task< ActionResult > Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var ResRecs = await _context.Reclamations
                .Where(r => r.IdClient == id)
                .Include(n => n.IdClientNavigation)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    observations = x.Observations,
                    rdv = x.Rdv,
                    explications = x.Explication,
                    idRec = x.Id,
                    pattern = x.Pattern

                })
                .OrderBy(t => t.rdv)
                .ToListAsync();
            var checkBoxes = new List<String>();
            foreach(var item in ResRecs)
            {
                if (item.pattern.Contains("DOTDelanteroIzquierdo")) checkBoxes.Add("DOTDelanteroIzquierdo"+item.idRec);
                if (item.pattern.Contains("DOTDelanteroDerecho")) checkBoxes.Add("DOTDelanteroDerecho" + item.idRec);
                if (item.pattern.Contains("DOTTraseroIzquierdo")) checkBoxes.Add("DOTTraseroIzquierdo" + item.idRec);
                if (item.pattern.Contains("DOTTraseroDerecho")) checkBoxes.Add("DOTTraseroDerecho" + item.idRec);
            }

            var  ResClient = await _context.Clients
               .Where(r => r.Id == id)
               .Select(x => new
               {
                   idClient = x.Id,
                   nameClient = x.FullName,
                   addressClient = x.Address,
                   postalCodeClient = x.PostalCode,
                   cityClient = x.City,
                   telClient = x.Tel,
                   emailClient = x.Email
               }).SingleAsync();
            return Content(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {ResClient, ResRec = ResRecs, Check = checkBoxes , success = true, message = "The Reclamation loaded"  }), "application/json");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error : " + ex);
        }
        return Content(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { success = false, message = "The Reclamation is not loaded" }), "application/json");

    }
```

Here is My Angular 5 Call service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppconfigService } from '../appconfig.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ReclamationsService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
     UrlRecs: string = AppconfigService.settings.server.url + "api/Reclamations/";
    getRec(idClient){

    return this.http.get(this.UrlRecs + "byClient/" + idClient);
}
}
```

Here is my component call of the service

```
this.reclamationSvc.getRec(this.idClient).subscribe(
  (response: Response) => {
    console.log('Before', response);
    if (response["success"] == true) {
       this.ResRecs = response["ResRec"];

      this.checkBoxs = response["Check"];

      this.c = response["ResClient"];


    }
    else {
      alert("Error");
    }

  },
  (error) => {

  }
)
```

I've been trying with this for 5 Days now, What could possibly be wrong with my code ?

Comment: What are you getting in logs on console and if also check the network request error code while you are calling the service from Client side. Do share the same here as well

Comment: Try to add `map` like this `return this.http.get(this.UrlRecs + "byClient/" + idClient).map((res: Response) => res.json() || {});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know. but try in API return OK

```
return OK(new {ResClient, ResRec = ResRecs, Check = checkBoxes , 
               success = true, message = "The Reclamation loaded"  });
```

And use dot notation in Angular

```
   if (response.success == true) {
      this.ResRecs = response.ResRec;
      this.checkBoxs = response.Check;
      this.c = response.ResClient;
    }
```